# What Is the new pandas update on groupby ? (FutureWarning)

Tags: python, pandas

```
DF.groupby(["Criteria"], as_index=False).apply(fn).groupby('Criteria').agg(d_agg1).round(2)
```

In the future, the group keys will be included in the index, regardless of whether the applied function returns a like-indexed object.
To preserve the previous behavior, use

```
    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=False)
```

What change are needed to be done in the code to avoid warning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `apply` and you make a `transform` operation, it will raise this warning because using `groupby_apply` with `as_index=False` should aggregate the group values and not maintain the number of rows (or columns). Use `apply` in last resort and prefer `agg` (to reduce) or `transform` (to broadcast) the result:

```
# Raise a warning
>>> DF.groupby(['Criteria'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x**2)
   Criteria  Value
0         0      1
1         1      4
2         1      9
3         0     16

# Without warning
>>> DF.groupby(['Criteria'], as_index=False).transform(lambda x: x**2)
   Value
0      1
1      4
2      9
3     16
```

As you can see, the output of `transform` is not the same as `apply` because the result of `transform` is ready to be appended to a new column of your original dataframe. So `as_index` doesn't matter in this case.

I think (but I'm not sure because `fn` and `d_agg1` are unknown) you can use:

```
d_agg1 = {'Value': [min, max]}
DF.groupby(['Criteria']).transform(lambda x: x**2).groupby(DF['Criteria']).agg(d_agg1)
```